# What paint to use on polystyrene ceiling rose

Tags: ceiling, paint

Does anyone know what kind of paint to use on a polystyrene ceiling rose? Thank you

Comment: No literature with the product? Most such things are designed with the expectation that you'll use the same paint you use for the ceiling.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the polystyrene trim pieces have a white coating already applied.

This can be painted over with acrylic latex.  If no coating is present use a latex primer.

Some suggest using a latex primer first to aid in color uniformity.

Use of oil based paint is not suggested.

Have a look at this [article on foam moldings](https://www.ehow.com/info_8007359_type-use-styrofoam-crown-molding.html) for more info